# Repeat value in the next n colums

Tags: excel, analysis

In the top table in the picture below (the one called input), I want to repeat all value to the next columns with the number in column B - i.e., for the value in C4, I want to repeat it in C4 and D4. The same should be true for the value in D4. The desired output is shown in the table below.

[image]

Can anybody help me? I find it very difficult to repeat the value whenever the values are overlapping (I cannot use VBA)

Thanks a lot!

Edit - here is an example:
Lets take the row 4 as an example: here I want to repeat the value 100 from cell C4 in cell C4 and cell D4. However in cell D4, I also want to repeat the value - i.e., the value in cell D4 needs to be in D4 and E4. Now, I want to sum the two, and therefore I get 100 in C4, 200 in D4 and 100 in E4.

Comment: Why output is mixed with 100 and 200? Any explanation?

Comment: Lets take the row 4 as an example: here I want to repeat the value 100 from cell C4 in cell C4 and cell D4. However in cell D4, I also want to repeat the value - i.e., the value in cell D4 needs to be in D4 and E4. Now, I want to sum the two, and therefore I get 100 in C4, 200 in D4 and 100 in E4. Sorry, this should have been explained better!

Comment: @Harun24HR, can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try copying this formula down and across starting in C11:

```
=IF(SUM(INDEX(4:4,MAX(COLUMN($C2),COLUMN()-$B11+1)):C4)=0,"",SUM(INDEX(4:4,MAX(COLUMN($C2),COLUMN()-$B11+1)):C4))
```

[image]